# Stop or reverse highlighting of clicked Vuetify v-tab item

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, tabs, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I have a VueJS/Vuetify application that has tab bars using `v-tabs`/`v-tab` components to navigate between pages. I have implemented code using the `click` event in the `v-tab` element that checks to make sure there is no unsaved content when the user clicks on another tab, and if there is, displays a modal using `v-dialog` to alert the user. If the user chooses to continue, it continues on to the desired tab/component. However, if the user selects `Cancel` in the modal, the page is left where it was.

Here is the tabs component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <v-tabs
      color="secondary"
      :value="currentTab"
    >
      <v-tab
        v-for="(tab, i) in userTabs"
        :key="i"
        :href="tab.href"
        @click="tabClick(tab.component, tab.link)"
        :disabled="isDisabled(tab)"
      >
        {{ tab.title }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <BaseConfirmModal
      :value="showUnsaved"
      :title="unsavedContentTitle"
      :text="unsavedContentText"
      declineText="Cancel"
      @clicked="unsavedModalConfirm"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import baseTabMixin from '@/components/mixins/workspace/baseTabMixin';

export default {
  name: 'UserTabs',
  data: () => ({
    userTabs: [
      {
        title: 'General Info',
        href: '#tab-general',
        link: 'tab-general',
        component: 'UserEdit',
      },
      {
        title: 'Enrollments',
        href: '#tab-enrollments',
        link: 'tab-enrollments',
        component: 'UserEnrollmentEdit',
      },
      {
        title: 'Alerts',
        href: '#tab-alerts',
        link: 'tab-alerts',
        component: 'UserAlertEdit',
      },
      {
        title: 'Devices',
        href: '#tab-devices',
        link: 'tab-devices',
        component: 'UserDeviceEdit',
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('app', ['getStickyTenant', 'roleAtLeastTa', 'getUnsaved']),
    ...mapGetters('users', ['getCurrent']),
    ...mapGetters('tabs', {
      currentTab: 'getSelected',
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('tabs', {
      setCurrentTab: 'setSelected',
    }),
    isDisabled(item) {
      if (item.component === 'UserEdit') {
        return false;
      }
      if (item.component === 'UserDeviceEdit' && !this.roleAtLeastTa) {
        return true;
      }

      return !this.getCurrent.userId;
    },
  },
  mixins: [baseTabMixin],
};
</script>
```

and the referenced `baseTabMixin`:

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

const baseTabMixin = {
  data: () => ({
    showUnsaved: false,
    unsavedContentTitle: 'Unsaved Changes',
    unsavedContentText: 'You have made changes to this page that are not saved. Do you wish to continue?',
    destTabComponent: '',
    destTabLink: '',
  }),
  components: {
    BaseConfirmModal: () => import('@/components/base/BaseConfirmModal'),
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('app', ['getUnsaved']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('app', ['setUnsaved']),
    tabClick(component, tab) {
      // Check to see if getUnsaved === true; if it is,
      // set variable to display warning modal.
      if (this.getUnsaved) {
        this.showUnsaved = true;
      } else {
        // There is no unsaved content, so continue to the desired tab.
        this.destTabComponent = component;
        this.destTabLink = tab;
        this.setCurrentTab(tab);
        this.$router.push({ name: component });
      }
    },
    unsavedModalConfirm(confirm) {
      if (confirm) {
        this.setCurrentTab(this.destTabLink);
        this.$router.push({ name: this.destTabComponent });
      }
      this.showUnsaved = false;
    },
  },
};

export default baseTabMixin;
```

The problem has to do with the tab item highlighting. When the new tab is clicked, the slider moves to the new tab and the new tab title is bolded before the click event (`tabClick()` in this case) is called. When I select `Cancel` in my modal, it leaves the page where it is (as expected), but the clicked tab is still highlighted, both with the slider underneath and the bolder text. Since that all happens before my click handler is even called, is there way to either a) stop the highlighting from happening before the click event is called, or b) reverse the highlighting back to the current tab?

Comment: have you tried @click.stop="tabCli... on your tab component?

Comment: @wheelmaker Yes, I tried both `@click.stop` and `@click.prevent`, and neither made a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link to working [pen](https://codepen.io/ParaBolt/pen/rNaVMPv).

Note the key parts of the code :-

```html
<v-tabs :value="currentTab" @change="onTabChange">
      <v-tab v-for="(tab, i) in tabs" :key="i">{{tab.title}}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

```js
async onTabChange(clickedTab)
{
    this.currentTab = clickedTab;
    await this.$nextTick();
    if (!this.allowTabChange) this.currentTab = this.previousTab;
    else this.previousTab = this.currentTab;
}
```

`v-tabs` component uses an internal model to maintain it's state i.e. which tab is currently active. Using the `:value` attribute, we can set an initial active tab. When the user clicks on a different tab, the internal model is updated leading to the clicked tab getting highlighted. `v-tabs` also emits a change event to notify the parent component of this change. We need to listen for this event and manage the `:value` variable by ourselves to maintain state in the parent. Since `v-model` is an abstraction over `:value` and `@change`, we could use that as well.

To listen for this change event, add `@change` to `v-tabs`. You can shift the entire logic that you have at `@click` to `@change` resulting in a cleaner code.

To prevent selection of the next tab, we need to use some tricky code since the internal model of `v-tabs` is not accessible to us. We need to allow `currentTab` to change temporarily to the clicked tab and then we reset it to `previousTab` in `$nextTick` i.e. after the current batch of updates has been picked up by Vue. The highlight beneath the tabs itself occurs after `$nextTick` so it will not change since we have reset the `:value` to `previousTab` by then.

If you are ok with letting the highlight temporarily shift to the new tab, then all you need to do is update `currentTab` to the index of next tab and the highlight will shift over as normal. Then depending on the decision made by user, you can set `currentTab` to `previousTab` to revert the change or you can update `previousTab` with the new value of `currentTab` i.e. the next tab. In this case the `$nextTick` hack is unnecessary.

Comment: A couple questions:
1) `currentTab` is already defined as a variable via `mapGetters`. so are you saying to overwrite it, or also set `previousTab` to the same value?
2) I can't really combine the code all into the `@changed` event, because I have to pass in the `component` and `link` values from the individual tab that is being selected. By default, it looks like I get the 'link' value, but not the component. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the explanation with a Codepen example that hopefully clears what I'm trying to convey. The pen also demonstrates how to get data associated with the clicked tab to answer #2.

Comment: Gibing credit to this answer, since it was used for my actual working code.

Comment: is the same true for `v-list/v-list-group`? I also have to implement the same functionality for a sidebar that uses those components.

Comment: For expand/collapse? The logic should work with any Vuetify component that implements value+change/v-model functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer by @ParaBolt and his CodePen, I got this working. My answer differed slightly from his because my `currentTab` is stored in state, not the component, and I also used a `filter` method to get the `component` value, but the structure is the same.

Here are the important parts of the mixin:

```
 data: () => ({
    ..
    previousTab: '',
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('app', ['setUnsaved']),
    async tabChange(newTab) {
      this.setCurrentTab(newTab);
      // We need to get the corresponding component value from the tabs array.
      const newComponent = this.tabList.filter(tab => tab.link === newTab)[0].component;
      // Stash these in case we need then in unsavedModalConfirm()
      this.destTabComponent = newComponent;
      this.destTabLink = newTab;
      // Check to see if getUnsaved === true; if it is,
      // set variable to display warning modal.
      await this.$nextTick();
      if (this.getUnsaved) {
        this.setCurrentTab(this.previousTab);
        this.showUnsaved = true;
      } else {
        // There is no unsaved content, so continue to the desired tab.
        this.setCurrentTab(newTab);
        this.$router.push({ name: newComponent });
      }
    },
    unsavedModalConfirm(confirm) {
      if (confirm) {
        // User selected Continue from modal.
        this.setCurrentTab(this.destTabLink);
        this.$router.push({ name: this.destTabComponent });
        this.setUnsaved(false);
      } else {
        // User selected Cancel
        this.setCurrentTab(this.previousTab);
      }
      this.showUnsaved = false;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.previousTab = this.currentTab;
  },
```

Whenever I cancel from the modal, it just stays where it is, and if I choose to continue, it goes on to the desired tab.